# error metodo sobrecargado en java

Tags: java, herencia, sobrecarga

Hola alquien me podria ayudar? nose porque me da este error.

```
abstract class Uno {
        protected int d1,d2;
        abstract public int devolver_suma (int x,int y);
}
class Dos extends Uno {
    public int devolver_suma(int x,int y) {
        d1=x+3;
        d2=y+3;
        return d1+d2;
    }

}
class Tres extends Dos {
    public int devolver_suma(int x,int y) {
        d1=x-3;
        d2=y-3;
        return d1+d2;
    }
    public int devolver_suma(int x,int y, int i, int j) {
        d1=x-i;
        d2=y-j;
        return d1+d2;
    }
}
class Principal {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int c=0,d=0;
        Uno []lista=new Uno[2];
        lista [0]= new Dos();
        lista [1]= new Tres();
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
            d=lista[i].devolver_suma(10,10);
            System.out.printf("d=%d \n",d);
            c=lista[i].devolver_suma(2,2,2,2); /*aqui me dice que que el metodo no es aplicable con esos argunmentos, osea que no se me sobrecarga.*/
            System.out.printf("c=%d \n",c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema te lo da porque `lista[i]` en la primera iteración del `for` es una instancia de la clase `Dos`. Esto provoca que la llamada al método `devuelve_suma` con cuatro parámetros de error, ya que la clase `Dos` no tiene este método declarado, sólo lo tiene con dos parámetros.

Deberías comprobar la clase a la que pertenece `lista[i]` para solucionar esto. Por supuesto, para este programa de ejemplo. En una aplicación real no deberías agrupar objetos de diferentes clases en un array, o al menos no realizar estas operaciones (sobrecarga de métodos y recorrer el array).

Puedes solucionarlo con este código:

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {    
  d=lista[i].devolver_suma(10,10);
  System.out.printf("d=%d \n",d);
  if(lista[i] instanceof Tres) {
    c=lista[i].devolver_suma(2,2,2,2);
    System.out.printf("c=%d \n",c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

_./

La solución es muy sencilla.

El problema te lo da porque `lista[i]` en la primera iteración del for es una instancia de la clase Dos. Esto provoca que la llamada al método `devuelve_suma()` con cuatro parámetros de error, ya que la clase Dos no tiene este método declarado, sólo lo tiene con dos parámetros.

El error es la iteración de la lista.

¡Mucha suerte! :D

Answer (score 0):

Debes de arreglarlo con la siguiente línea:

```
c=((Tres)lista[i]).devolver_suma(2,2,2,2);
```

**¿Por qué?**

> Porque la clase abstracta que vas heredando no posee ese número de
>   parámetros, no posee ni esa función a ese nivel que lo intentas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu arreglo está declarado como si las variables fuesen de tipo `Uno`, aquí:

```
Uno[] lista = new Uno[2];
```

En Java, al trabajar con una variable, solo se pueden acceder a los miembros (atributos y métodos) que se encuentren en el tipo de clase definido para la variable. La clase `Uno` no posee un método con la firma `int devolver_suma(int, int, int, int)`, por ende el error de compilación. No importa si inicializas los elementos del arreglo como si fuesen de la clase `Dos` o `Tres`, el compilador solo comprende que los elementos de `lista` son de tipo `Uno`.

Para resolver esto, la mejor alternativa es utilizar casteo hacia abajo (downcasting en inglés). Esto es, que una variable definida de tipo de clase se comporte como una clase de un tipo que hereda o extiende de dicha clase. En este caso, sería que las variables en tu arreglo `Uno[] lista` se comporten como un tipo específico `Dos` o `Tres`. Para asegurar que se hace el casteo hacia abajo correcto, se puede utilizar el operador `instanceof`:

```
if (lista[i] instanceof Tres) {
    c=lista[i].devolver_suma(2,2,2,2);
    System.out.printf("c=%d \n",c);
}
```

---

> ```
> c=lista[i].devolver_suma(2,2,2,2); /*aqui me dice que que el metodo no es aplicable con esos argunmentos, osea que no se me sobrecarga.*/
> ```

La sobrecarga funciona correctamente, pero solo es para el método `devolver_suma` definido en la clase `Tres`. La sobrecarga de métodos (overloading) funciona sobre una sola clase, mientras que la herencia y polimorfismo de métodos funciona entre la clase ancestro y sus descendientes.

Answer (score -1):

El error se da porque la función solo va funcionar con esa firma si y solo si **i = 1** (`lista [1]= new Tres()`), la primera vez que ingresa al ciclo **i = 0** (`lista [0]= new Dos()`), a ese nivel no existe la definición de tu función con esa firma por eso levanta una excepción.

Basicamente la unica forma en la que va funcionar es asi:

```
c=lista[1].devolver_suma(2,2,2,2);
```

Otra opcion seria haciendo el casteo explicito:

```
c=(Tres)lista[0].devolver_suma(2,2,2,2);
```